# Heroku run command not a command/working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I'm using nitrous IDE and working on a rails project. Whenever I do "heroku run.." it says run command not found. Also this:

Perhaps you meant `-h`, `2fa`, `auth`, `join`, `open`, `orgs`, `pg`, `ps` or `rake`.
 !    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.

The toolbelt is installed. Version is uptodate. Location of heroku is usr/bin/heroku. etc. Don't know why it's not working. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been having this problem too. Talked to Heroku support. Try this:

rm -rf ~/.heroku/

then do:

GODE_DEBUG=info heroku update

That worked for me. If you installed any custom plugins they will have to be reinstalled afterwards though I think.

Comment: I actually came upon an answer similar. After removing all I needed to do was 'heroku update' which solved it. :)